# Not seeing OSX desktop notifications with test app closed (Lion)

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I am testing Push notifications in an OSX sample app (based on PushyMac).

I have development push notifications working - I can send a push, and with the application open I receive the notifications in the application just fine.  I forward them at that time into the Notification Center so they can be seen.

However what I can't figure out is how notifications are supposed to appear in Notification Center when the application is not running.  With the application shut off, notifications I send never appear in notification center and my application does not receive them on launch.

To make sure I was really getting the notifications, I turned on OSX APNS logging as per this document:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG24

I had to correct the commands a bit for OS X Lion, which changed the APNS service name to simply "apns" - so the logging commands are now:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.apsd APSWriteLogs -bool TRUE
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.apsd APSLogLevel -int 7
sudo killall apsd
```

After doing that, in the logs I can see my push notification is received by the system:

```
<APSCourier: 0x7fe704a262b0>: Received message for enabled topic 'io.push.desktopsample' with payload '<CFBasicHash 0x7fe704a4e340 [0x7fff73447110]>{type = immutable dict, count = 2,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x7fe704a3f690 [0x7fff73447110]>{contents = "aps"} = <CFBasicHash 0x7fe704a4cd50 [0x7fff73447110]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x7fe704a3de00 [0x7fff73447110]>{contents = "alert"} = <CFString 0x7fe704a3ff10 [0x7fff73447110]>{contents = "Test Push 8"}
    }

        1 : <CFString 0x7fe704a4e7a0 [0x7fff73447110]>{contents = "ei"} = <CFString 0x7fe704a50b80 [0x7fff73447110]>{contents = "POly"}
    }
    '
```

But as I said, nothing in the Notification Center.  Any ideas why the notifications are not appearing?  Do only production APNS pushes reach notification center?

Comment: can you paste some code of setting up PN?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't paste the code in as I'm working on a proprietary library.  But the application delegate does get didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: called with a valid token, and as I said I can receive notifications just fine with the app open so I know it's properly registered with APNS. It doesn't seem like a code-related issue, unless there is push configuration code I need to add to OSX which is not required in IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PushyMac app code was written during OSX 10.7 and the only notification type available was Badge. If you are running OSX 10.8, then add the alert notification type as well, as shown below.

[NSApp registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(NSRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | NSRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)]

However, after doing this, I am not able to launch the app by clicking on the alert in notification area. If you find an answer for that, please do reply.

Comment: I actually did discover this was my problem earlier, but forgot to update my question so I'll award you the answer (and it's great to know that in the past only badge was supported).  I'm not yet seen if clicking on the alert launches the app, will report back...